# Query con LEFT JOIN y LIMIT 1 en el JOIN no me funciona

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes 2 tablas `order` y `tracking`. Las estructuras son las siguientes:

`Order` (*columnas y datos*):

```
id fecha       nroorder description
1  2017-22-01  1000001  Order1
2  2017-22-01  1000002  Order2
3  2017-22-01  1000003  Order3
```

`Tracking` (*columnas y datos*):

```
id idorder idstatus
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  1       3
4  2       1
5  2       2
6  3       1
7  3       2
```

La cuestión a todo esto es que yo necesito que me devuelva cada `order` con el `tracking` de `idstatus` más alto, es decir, que necesito que me devuelva:

```
order.id order.fecha order.nroorder order.description tracking.idstatus
1        2017-22-01  1000001        Order1            3
2        2017-22-01  1000002        Order2            2
3        2017-22-01  1000003        Order3            2
```

Probé con la siguiente instrucción (en realidad con varias pero esta es la que más se acerca):

```
SELECT `order`.*, d.*
 FROM `order` left JOIN (SELECT tracking.* 
         FROM tracking
        ORDER BY tracking.id DESC limit 1) d
ON `order`.`id` = d.idorder
```

A `tracking` lo ordeno por `id`, para sacar el último, porque por regla de negocio los `tracking` van aumentando su `idstatus` a medida que se insertan.

¿Qué es lo que está mal o lo que me falta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta cambiando la consulta así. De la manera que lo tienes, el subquery solo te va a traer un registro de todos los que hay y lo que tu necesitas es un registro por cada orden.

```
SELECT `order`.*, d.idstatus
FROM `order` LEFT JOIN (SELECT tracking.idorder, MAX(tracking.idstatus) As idstatus  
         FROM tracking
        GROUP BY tracking.idorder) d
ON `order`.`id` = d.idorder
```

Comment: Excelente solucion! Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Una subconsulta podría solucionar tu pregunta:

```
SELECT O.*, 
(SELECT tracking.idstatus 
        FROM tracking T
        WHERE T.idorder = O.id
        ORDER BY tracking.id DESC limit 1)
FROM `order` O
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás haciendo el `LIMIT` en el `JOIN`; con eso sólo traes una fila de `tracking` en vez de una por cada fila de `order`.

Esta consulta hace lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT
    `order`.id,
    `order`.fecha,
    `order`.nroorder,
    `order`.description,
    tracking.idstatus

FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN tracking
    ON tracking.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM tracking
        WHERE tracking.idorder = `order`.id
        ORDER BY tracking.id DESC
        LIMIT 1);
```